# Powershell Remove Specific Characters Beginning and End of Filename

Tags: powershell, file-rename

I am working on cleaning up a directory but I am having trouble with my PowerShell code.  Specifically finding specific characters in specific places and removing them.

Here is what my directory currently looks like...

```
_AB_.CDF
_AB__.CDF
_AB__0.CDF
_AB__1.CDF
_GH_.IJK
_GH__.IJK
_GH__0.IJK
_GH__1.IJK
L_M_N_O_.PQR
L_M_N_O__.PQR
L_M_N_O__0.PQR
```

What I want to do is trim out any underscores in the beginning of the filename and any underscores followed by numbers (if present) at the end.  So it looks like this...

```
AB.CDF
GH.IJK
L_M_N_O.PQR
```

Here is the code I have come up with so far...

```
Set-Location C:\somedir
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    $NewName = ($_.BaseName -Replace "^_|_|\d+$") + $_.Extension
    $Destination = Join-Path -Path $_.Directory.FullName -ChildPath $NewName
    Move-Item -LiteralPath $_.FullName -Destination $Destination -Force
}
```

And it almost does the trick.  However, it also removes all instances of underscores leaving me with files without any underscores that I want to keep. Like this...

```
LMNO.PQR
```

I am sure this question is probably answered in another post, but the last few hours of searching have left me depleted.  Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 3):

I'd go for the [`String.TrimStart()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimstart(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`String.TrimEnd()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimend(v=vs.110).aspx) methods rather than regex:

```
$NewName = $_.BaseName.TrimStart('_').TrimEnd('_0123456789')
```

---

If you want to use regex, this is probably the pattern you're looking for:

```
$_.BaseName -replace '^_+|[_\d]+$'
```

Comment: I folded your solution into mine but then another problem reared its ugly head.  This is a large folder and while I thought I had accounted for all different types of filenames, one ended up with a funky name.

Prior to the script, the filename was 12a3456_7.bcd.  After the script, it was renamed to 12a.bcd.  I'm curious as to why?

Comment: @sudosysadmin: You wanted to trim underscores and numbers at the end of the filename (without changing the extension). Trimming `12a3456_7` to `12a` fits that definition.

Comment: I edited my question to make it more clear.  I need to remove any underscores followed by any numbers (if present).

Answer (score 1):

You're wanting [Trim Start](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimstart(v=vs.110).aspx) and [TrimEnd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimend(v=vs.110).aspx)

In Powershell the syntax would be

```
$stringVar.TrimStart('_').TrimEnd('_')
```

Here's the results from my Console:L

```
 PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $stringVar = "_AB_"
 PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $StringVar.TrimStart('_').TrimEnd('_')
 AB
 PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $stringVar = "L_M_N_O__"
 PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $StringVar.TrimStart('_').TrimEnd('_')
 L_M_N_O
```

And then recombine it with your filetype as you were before.